# How do I calculate the center of gravity under this curve?

Tags: probability

Looking at section Defuzzification [here](http://petro.tanrei.ca/fuzzylogic/fuzzy_negnevistky.html) for this image.

They show the answer as:

```
(0+10+20)*0.1 + (30+40+50+60)*0.2 + (70+80+90+100)*0.5 /   
(0.1*3) + (0.2*4) + (0.5*4)   
= 67.4
```

I see how the numerator is calculated but any help on the denominator is appreciated, espicially the *3,*4,*4

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

They appear to have assumed that the area to take the centroid of consists of a rectangle of area $10\times0.1$ centered at 0, two more rectangles of the same size centered at $10$ and $20$, four rectangles of area $10\times0.2$ centered at $30$, $40$, $50$, and $60$, respectively, and four more rectangles of area $10\times0.5$ centered at $70$, $80$, $90$, and $100$ respectively. Now, we can see that the is clearly not what the diagram shows--there is nothing to the left of $0$ and nothing to the right of $100$, so we can hardly say that anything with positive area is centered at either of those values, and moreover there are some distinctly non-rectangular features between $20$ and $30$ and between $60$ and $70$. But if their assumptions were an accurate way of taking the centroid, then the denominator of their formula would be the total area of the object whose centroid they're finding.  The $3$, $4$, and $4$ come from the fact that they assume three rectangles of the smallest size, four of the intermediate size, and four more of the largest size. And for some reason they've chosen to take each rectangle at $1/10$ its actual size, but they've done that on both the top and bottom of the formula so it all cancels out.

Comment: interesting....yet weird...not sure I really get how they assumed these things.